# Expo Client does not save changes

Tags: react-native, expo

Im very new to react-native and expo.
I can't solve this problem myself.
My previous code was this.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  handleSignOut = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(result => alert('sign out success'))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Main</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleSignOut}>
          <Text>Sign Out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Then I just changed the text 'Main' to 'Home' and saved.
After that expo client was reloaded but nothing changed :(

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices!

Comment: Hmm, weird. I couldn't see any mistakes, so I just spun off a quick Expo project to check, copy pasted your code (minus the firebase parts) and it's working fine for me. Updates on every change. Maybe try closing and reopening your emulator/simulator. BTW, please share your expo-cli version by running `expo --version` in your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for responding. As you said, I closed and restarted expo then it worked!

Comment: Ha! Awesome. Feel free to accept my answer (below) as the correct answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of Expo you're using (`expo --version`), but I spun off a quick Expo project, copy pasted your code (minus the Firebase parts) and it works seamlessly.

Maybe try closing and reopening your emulator/simulator.